# Chrome browser in android refreshes the page after taking more than one image using the device's camera

Tags: javascript, android, html, reactjs, web

I'm working on react js project that needs to take many images using the camera of an android device.

we used
`<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">`

Some Android devices automatically refresh the page after taking two or three photos, while another device refreshes the page after taking seven photos and some time we got this message `unable to complete previous operation due to low memory`

Note: It's not the same problem on iOS devices, and some Android devices work fine as well

Comment: first you need to narrow down whether it's the android/browser version that causes this problem or the device itself

Comment: @MaestroDever it's happening in different devices and most of them have the latest version of the android and browser

Comment: Each `file input should allow exactly one file to be uploaded.  Do you have multiple inputs to allow multiple images?